# PHP not executing on certain files, is executing properly on others

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to migrate an existing PHP website to a new server `(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server)` and have configured `phpMyAdmin, PHP 7.2.24, and Apache2`.  I can see and view the `index.php` file but no PHP inside it is executing.  However when I access my `info.php` file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` I can successfully see the PHP info, meaning it's being properly executed.

Any ideas?  It seems my Apache2 conf is set up correctly, given that I can access everything and PHP even runs, but I don't know why it won't execute on other pages...

I've checked my error log, it seems like there's a problem `Undefined Function` calling a function`printCallLink`that is being added from the `head.php`line. This would seem to indicate to me that for some reason the file head.php isn't being properly loaded in.

site.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin web@localhost
    ServerName tpcrn.com
    ServerAlias www.tpcrn.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tpcrn.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Index.php data:

````
<?

if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/admin/') === 0 ){
    include_once 'admin.php';
    exit;
}

if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'pc-repair-') !== FALSE && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-computer-services') !== FALSE ){
    include_once 'locations/default.php';
    exit;
}

include_once 'inl/head.php';
?>```
````

Comment: Add your apache config to the post.

Comment: Saying "no PHP inside it is executing" isn't really helpful. Check your error logs. Is Apache not finding the file? Are your `include_once()` calls throwing any warnings about not being able to find the files? Are there permissions errors? Is it possible that your `.htaccess` file isn't configured properly (i.e. it's not directing all requests to your `index.php` file)? There are several possible causes for your problem, so narrowing things down by looking for generated errors will help you tremendously.

Comment: @B.Fleming Thanks for the suggestions.  I've checked my error log, it seems like there's a problem `Undefined Function` calling a function `printCallLink` that is being added from the `head.php` line.  This would seem to indicate to me that for some reason the file head.php isn't being properly loaded in.

Comment: @JoeWHoward That would suggest to me that `head.php` contains the offending function call, and that your `printCallLink` function is defined in a different file that you haven't included prior to invoking it. You'll want to ensure that you're not missing any files, using an out of date version of your project, or failing to include external dependencies (speaking of dependencies, you'll also want to ensure that your dependencies are the correct versions). Honestly, there's not much more we can do to help you with only the information you've provided here.

Comment: You've tagged this with 'phpmyadmin' but your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application, so I've edited and removed the tag for you.